# Add type annotations to Lua function that merges two tables and make the LSP track the keys

Tags: generics, lua

I'm trying to type a Lua function using generics so that the Lsp (in this case sumneko-lua) that is able to keep track of the properties of all the tables involved. Currently I was not able to find a way, so I would love some help here.

Let me write the simplest example of what I want:

```lua
local foo = { a = true }
local bar = { b = true }
-- merge is the function I'm trying to type
local fooBar = merge(foo, bar)
```

I want fooBar to have type `{a: boolean, b: boolean}`. Ideally I want the function to accept any number of tables to merge, but I will be fine if I have to write a set of fixed overloads to accept up to X table merges.

Some things that I tried that didn't worked were:

```lua
---@generic T
---@generic A { [string]: T }
---@generic O { [string]: T }
---@param ... O|A
---@return O
function M.merge(...)

---Assigns the properties of one or more objects to another object
---@generic X
---@generic Y
---@generic A { [string]: X }
---@generic B { [string]: Y }
---@generic O { [string]: X | Y }
---@param a A
---@param b B
---@return O
function M.merge(a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am fumbling with sumneko_lua these days, too.

Trying out different approaches, I came up with a solution which could solve the issue with a fixed number of arguments:

```lua
---@generic T1 : table
---@generic T2 : table
---@param a T1
---@param b T2
---@return T1 | T2
local function merge(a, b) end

local foo = { a = true }
local bar = { b = "true" }

--[[ local fooBar: {
    a: boolean = true,
    b: string = "true",
} ]]
local fooBar = merge(bar, foo)
```

Interestingly, the solution works when nesting calls.
Therefore, you will be able to do:

```lua
local foo = { a = true }
local bar = { b = "true" }
local baz = { c = 1 }

--[[ local fooBarBaz: {
    a: boolean = true,
    b: string = "true",
    c: integer = 1,
} ]]
local fooBarBaz = merge(merge(foo, bar), baz)
```

I was instead not able to make it work with a variable number of arguments, since it seems the language server applies the inferred type of the first to all arguments.

You can find all supported annotations documented in the [language server wiki](https://github.com/sumneko/lua-language-server/wiki/Annotations)